# PostingStyle of NotificationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have learned that when using NotificationQueue to post notifications, you can choose a postingStyle. This is an enumeration with three main values: `whenIdle`, `asap`, and `now`.

Among them, `now` represents synchronous posting, which is no different from using the `post` method of NotificationCenter.

My question is, both `whenIdle` and `asap` seem to rely on the Runloop to determine the timing of asynchronous posting. What conditions should I consider when deciding which asynchronous posting method is most appropriate?

```swift
    public enum PostingStyle : UInt, @unchecked Sendable {

        
        case whenIdle = 1

        case asap = 2

        case now = 3
    }
```

Comment: I don't think your description of `now` is correct. The documentation states: *"The notification is posted immediately after coalescing."* so it does not appear to be synchronous nor the same as `NotificationCenter post`, unless the coalescing is set to `none`.

Comment: @HangarRash Sorry, I didn't mention `coalescing`, I actually chose `none`